# How to load Kivy RecycleView based on changing variables from other classes?

Tags: python, class, kivy, initialization, kivy-recycleview

I'm trying to create a RecycleView that lists a number of items that changes depending on the selected day, and only shows the items for a particular user. I've created a login function for my app that, when called, sets the current_user to the user id in the database. My problem I believe is that when I run the app, the RecycleView is created using the default value (0) before I've even loaded the screen it's on. Is there a way to delay the initialization of the RecycleView so that it will accept the new App.get_running_app().current_user and App.get_running_app.current_day_id values?

I know that the values are being updated correctly because when I login and choose a date and try to print the values it prints the changed value instead of the default.

The way it works is I login , which sets the App.get_running_app().current_user value and displays the Home screen. Then when I select a date, it sets the App.get_running_app().current_day_id and displays the screen for that day, which is where the RecycleView is displayed.

Relevent Code listed below

```
# My RV claass
class SnapshotsRV(MDRecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SnapshotsRV, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        conn = sqlite3.connect("site.db")
        c = conn.cursor()

        # with these two variables, I want to get the updated values. Not the values that I set 
        initially
        user = App.get_running_app().current_user
        day = App.get_running_app().current_day_id

        c.execute("SELECT * FROM snapshot WHERE user_id=? AND day=?", (user, day,))

        snapshots = c.fetchall()
        self.data = [{'text': snapshot[2]} for snapshot in snapshots]

        conn.commit()
        conn.close()


class JournalApp(MDApp):
    #Set the initial values
    current_user = NumericProperty(0)
    current_date = StringProperty("")
    current_day_id = NumericProperty(None)

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file('app.kv')
```

Any help is appreciated. I'm self taught and still learning!

Comment: Unless the number of items you are displaying is quite large, Using a `RecycleView` may be over complication. A Simple `BoxLayout` in a `ScrollView` may be a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've figured it out, at least part way. It seems the way to do this is to call on_pre_enter(), which has to be called on a screen instead of on a RecycleView. I created a function to get the rv data, and a function to set the data, both within the DateView, the class containing the RV, then called those methods in on_pre_enter() which loads dynamically the data when the day is chosen.

In order to reset it when the user goes back to the home page and chooses a different day, I created a clear_rv_data() function, that will set the data to an empty list. This will be updated each time the page is visited

in my kv file:

```
<SnapshotsRV>
    viewclass: 'MDRaisedButton'
    RecycleBoxLayout:
        default_size: None, 100
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation: 'vertical'

<DateView>
    snapshots_rv: snapshots_rv
    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        id: snapshot_grid
        SnapshotsRv:
            id: snapshots_rv
    MDRaisedButton:
        text: "Home"
        on_release: app.root.current = "home"; root.clear_rv_data()
```

and my python file

```
class DateView(MDScreen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(DateView, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_pre_enter(self, *args):
        rv_data = self.get_rv_data()
        
        # use the id to update the recycleview data
        for snapshot in rv_data:
            self.ids.snapshots_rv.data = [{'text': snapshot[2]} for snapshot in rv_data]

    def clear_rv_data(self):
        #this resets the data when the screen is left, so that when a new day is chosen it can show the updated data
        self.snapshots_rv.data = []
        self.ids.snapshots_rv.refresh_from_data()

    def get_rv_data(self):
        conn = sqlite3.connect("site.db")
        c = conn.cursor()
        
        day = App.get_running_app().current_day_id
        user = App.get_running_app().current_user
        c.execute("SELECT * FROM snapshot where user_id == ? AND day_id=?", (user, day,))
        snapshots = c.fetchall()

        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
        return snapshots


class JournalApp(MDApp):
    current_user = NumericProperty(0)
    current_day_id = NumericProperty(0)
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file('app.kv')
```